# Angular JS img tag not working if I use scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Does anyone know why my code stops working in IE 11 when using  tag like this:

```
<img blabla ng-src="{{test.bla.path }}">
```

I printed out the test.bla.path and did this:

```
<img blabla ng-src=" and I copied the text that top scope returned in here ">
```

and it worked. O.O

The image displays but I do things with this image after it loads but this just seems to not work on IE 11 if I do it like I did in first example, cause it works on every other browser.

Comment: Did you use <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />?

Comment: Yes I did. Doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Do you have any erros in a console?

Comment: And pls add a code of your controller.

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle.